# Setting footer in dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

This is the required [behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/asirila/82ZU8/102/)(jsfiddle).

```
<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
<span class="alignleft">$unique_ID</span>
<span class="alignright"> Page <span class="pagenum"></span></span>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>



.footer {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
.footer {
bottom: 0px;
}

.pagenum:before {
content: counter(page);
}
.alignleft {
float: left;
}
.alignright {
float: right;
}
```

[image]
But when using the exact same code in the html which the dobmpdf uses to render following is the result
[image]

How to solve this problem.
($unique_ID is a php variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dompdf up to and including version 0.6.2 does not have float support enabled by default. Modify your dompdf_config.custom.inc.php file such that the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT` configuration constant is set to true.

Dompdf up to and including version 0.7.0 does not support auto-calculated width. So even enabling float will not be enough for these versions. You will need to add a width to your floated elements for them to display correctly.

Dompdf 0.7.1 and later should render this as expected.